# How should I change this html snippet so the text Hello World is vertically on the middle of the screen?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <table cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

The result of that html snippet is the word Hello World is on top of the screen. I did everything to make it in the middle. What can I do?

I tried another way using vertical align style

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>How to get Sexier Avatar in IMVU 2</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
<div style="height: 100%;width: 100%;vertical-align: middle">
<h1>Click here to Get Game and See Yourself</h1>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I clearly said that the vertical align for the div should be middle. It doesn't work.

It seems that the size of the body is not fullscreen. How do I make it full screen?

Comment: Its 2017. Why are you using table for layouts?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried. Update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Title</title>
<style>
#centerInScreen {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#centerInScreen h1 {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="centerInScreen">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use this to center in screen.

Comment: @JimThio try to add 2-3 lines and see with and without transform. You'll see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS

```
<div class="center">Hello World</div>

.center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* margin is -0.5 * dimension */
    margin-top: -25px; 
}​
```

Comment: I want the text to be flexible. So the size is not known before hand. I don't think it's possible at all.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I've just shown you. the width/height is merely for the container